# Error in reading a txt file on HDFS and copying/writing the content of it into a newly created file on LOCAL filesystem

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read a file on HDFS and copy the content of the file into a newly created local file using the following java program. FYI, I have installed hadoop single node cluster on my machine.

HdfsCli.java

```
package com;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HdfsCli {
public void readFile(String file) throws IOException {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String hadoopConfPath = "\\opt\\hadoop\\etc\\hadoop\\";
    conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfPath + "core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfPath + "hdfs-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path(hadoopConfPath + "mapred-site.xml"));

    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
    // For the join type of queries, output file in the HDFS has 'r' in it.
    // String type="r";

    Path path = new Path(file);
    if (!fileSystem.exists(path)) {
        System.out.println("File " + file + " does not exists");
        return;
    }

    FSDataInputStream in = fileSystem.open(path);

    String filename = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
            file.length());

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
            new File("/home/DAS_Pig/" + filename)));

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int numBytes = 0;
    while ((numBytes = in.read(b)) > 0) {
        out.write(b, 0, numBytes);
    }
    conf.clear();
    in.close();
    out.close();
    fileSystem.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HDFSClient hc = new HDFSClient();
    hc.readFile("hdfs://localhost:9000//DasData//salaries.txt");

    System.out.println("Successfully Done!");
}

}
```

However, when I am running this code, the following error is coming:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9           cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at com.HDFSClient.readFile(HDFSClient.java:22)
    at com.HdfsCli.main(HdfsCli.java:57)
```

I am newb in hadoop development. Can anyone guide me in resolving this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Server and client versions are different. Looks like server version is 4.i, and client is 3.i. You have to upgrade client classpath libraries up to server version.

Comment: Can you provide a little more details on this? BTW what is 4.i and 3.i?

Comment: Look at solution here: http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/server-ipc-version-9/

Comment: so the client and nodes' jars don't match, right? That a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all current hadoop jars depencies included in your project. Download a newer version of Hadoop. Configure a build path of your project with new jars.